# Accessing info from blizzards website/api

Tags: api

i want to be able to pull info from several different character info sites such as https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-gb/character/ragnaros/armory into my python program, primarily I only am interested in the stat descriptions of each item which i would then do calculations with.

How would I go about doing this? I registered with blizzard for access to their api and while I have a working knowledge of python I have no experience in web scraping/api.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options for Web Scraping in Python.

[BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is one of the more popular options for web scraping with plenty of good resources online detailing its use.

[Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) is another option that you can look at it as well.